# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined : Sessions

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

All required modules/imports are placed correctly yet I am facing the error as **req.session.isAuthenticated** is undefined.
But even if it is undefined, it should compared with some value ( req.session.isAuthenticated == 'undefined )

```
const isAuthorized = (res, req, next) => {
    console.log('Value > ',req.session.isAuthenticated) // this req.session.isAuthenticated is giving error
    
    if(req.session.isAuthenticated){ // this req.session.isAuthenticated is giving error
        next()
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login')
    }
}


myApp.get('/MainPage', isAuthorized ,function(req, res){ 
    res.status(200).render('MainPage', {
        username: ''
    });
});
```

MONGO DB Session Document :

```
{
  "_id": "cNPM4diVlq3ql96xhIXUQX357ABypdVz",
  "expires": {
    "$date": "2023-12-20T18:24:05.210Z"
  },
  "session": {
    "cookie": {
      "originalMaxAge": null,
      "expires": null,
      "secure": null,
      "httpOnly": true,
      "domain": null,
      "path": "/",
      "sameSite": null
    }
  }
}
```

ERROR :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isAuthenticated')
    at isAuthorized (src\index.js:60:52)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (src\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (src\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (src\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (src\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at src\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (src\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (src\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at session (src\node_modules\express-session\index.js:479:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (src\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

I am trying to redirect to login page if anyone enters inner page URL (/MainPage) without logging in.

I am not sure whether I should initialize `req.session.isAuthenticated` to some value so as DB document create this property.

Comment: req.session is too undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const app = express();

app.use(session({
  secret: 'your_secret_here', // 
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false
}));


app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  // Assuming authentication was successful
  req.session.isAuthenticated = true; // or you can use the mongo session you want to use
  res.send('Logged in successfully!');
});

// then do this on logout
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  // Logging out, so setting isAuthenticated to false
  req.session.isAuthenticated = false;
  res.send('Logged out successfully!');
});
```

Then you can have your middleware this way

```js
const isAuthorized = (res, req, next) => {
    console.log('Value > ',req.session.isAuthenticated) // true 
    
    // if true move to the next middleware, else redirect to login
    if(req.session.isAuthenticated){
        next()
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login')
    }
}


myApp.get('/MainPage', isAuthorized ,function(req, res){ 
    res.status(200).render('MainPage', {
        username: ''
    });
});
```